# Destruct an object type into an "or" type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Does Typescript support type/interface "destructing" (if I can call it that)
So I'm trying to do something along the following line:

```
type SomeRandomType = {
    propertyOne: string;
    propertyTwo: number;
    ...
};

type SomeRandomORType = "propertyOne" | "propertyTwo" | ...;
```

So is it supported to create the `SomeRandomORType` without manually typing properties from `SomeRandomType`? Something line

```
type SomeRandomORType = Destruct<SomeRandomType>;
```

Comment: Would `type SomeRandomOrType = keyof SomeRandomType;` work here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) operator to get a type that could be a string ( or number ) with the name of each property of the interface / object. This seams to be what you are looking for.

```
interface myInterface {

    property1: string;
    property2: string;
    property3: number;
}

type keysOfMyInterface = keyof myInterface;

// this is valid since the property "property1" exists in the interface.
const variable1: keysOfMyInterface = "property1";

// this is not valid, since it was not a key from the interface.
const variable2: keysOfMyInterface = "property4";
```

You can try it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLYE8CS5rycgbwCgjkzkAHKAewujHQEYAuZAZzClAHMBuU8lVr10AJlYcuIPgLJC6UBgGZWIAK6oARtH4BfEgzrIA1hHRsA8jACyWHLEQoAvCbPUYaO5AdJ+RBNQgHMgAbnBccJoANhAsruZWttjeeM7IAETyIozpfgD0echgABbAbMhlyCDUYKFwUcAAJgA07KD4wLUA7nDl1bVw8cgwNKhFxSigKY4AdP6BwWER0RDi8ZY2XriOyC6ZNAoMACy5QA)